# Android Google People API connection is always null

Tags: android, google-api-client, google-people-api

I am trying to run the Google People API [sample code](https://github.com/Suleiman19/People-API-App) by following the steps [here](http://blog.grafixartist.com/people-api-android-tutorial-2/). Unfortunately it's always got a null connections from `response.getConnections()` of ListConnectionsResponse. Below AsyncTask is executed in `onActivityResult` after sign in successful:

```
class PeoplesAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        updateUI();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... params) {

        List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            People peopleService = PeopleHelper.setUp(MainActivity.this, params[0]);

            ListConnectionsResponse response = peopleService.people().connections()
                    .list("people/me").setRequestMaskIncludeField("person.names,person.emailAddresses,person.phoneNumbers")
                    .execute();
            List<Person> connections = response.getConnections();

            //error: connections is always null
            for (Person person : connections) {
                if (!person.isEmpty()) {
                    List<Name> names = person.getNames();
                    List<EmailAddress> emailAddresses = person.getEmailAddresses();
                    List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = person.getPhoneNumbers();

                    if (phoneNumbers != null)
                        for (PhoneNumber phoneNumber : phoneNumbers)
                            Log.d(TAG, "phone: " + phoneNumber.getValue());

                    if (emailAddresses != null)
                        for (EmailAddress emailAddress : emailAddresses)
                            Log.d(TAG, "email: " + emailAddress.getValue());

                    if (names != null)
                        for (Name name : names)
                            nameList.add(name.getDisplayName());

                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return nameList;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> nameList) {
        super.onPostExecute(nameList);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        adapter = new PeopleAdapter(nameList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

What are the reasons causing null response connections in Google People API and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a misunderstanding, `ListConnectionsResponse response = peopleService.people().connections() .list("people/me")` is not for user's profile and it's for user connections' profiles. If you need the user's personal profile information:

```
Person profile = peopleService.people().get("people/me").execute();

            if (!profile.isEmpty()) {

                List<Name> names = profile.getNames();
                List<Birthday> birthdays = profile.getBirthdays();
                List<Gender> genders = profile.getGenders();
                List<Url> urls = profile.getUrls();
                List<EmailAddress> emailAddresses = profile.getEmailAddresses();
                List<Photo> profileImages = profile.getPhotos();

                String displayName = names.get(0).getDisplayName();
                String birthday = birthdays.get(0).getText();
                String gender = genders.get(0).getValue();
                String email = emailAddresses.get(0).getValue();
                String profileImage = profileImages.get(0).getUrl();

            }
```

Comment: But still why is response.getConnections(); null in the question?

Comment: when you don't have friend in list i believe

Comment: I am getting empty Strings. I am using Your code. I am getting Name, ImageUrl and Email IDs, but other fields are returning empty. can you help me with that?

Comment: @JayDangar have you key in those fields in your account ?

Comment: @BeeingJk, I have provided Client and Secret IDs, but didn't work.

Comment: @JayDangar have you inserted those profile information in your google account ? if not, you will just get empty

Comment: @BeeingJk, I checked API on Browser via providing parameters inside setPersonFields method and i Am getting results for those empty String.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create an API console project? I found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project) a tutorial for a similar API